# How to delete a table row from UI (Delete Button at the end of the each row) by primary key using activity in PEGA

Tags: pega

I have a requirement to delete a table row by placing a delete button at the end of each row from the UI.

Can anyone help me with the activity steps to perform this action? with some screenshots, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set a visibility property when click action on button and refresh the section.
There should be a row visibility on table settings.
And display only visible row on table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).